# How to install Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 3.0 in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, installation, windows-installer, dockerfile

I'm attempting to containerize a legacy ASP.NET application that has a dependency on [Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089).  I understand that this is a legacy technology but refactoring the application to remove it is not an option.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis
RUN mkdir prereqs
WORKDIR /prereqs
COPY ["prereqs/WSE30.msi", "c:/prereqs/"]
RUN "C:\prereqs\WSE30.msi /qn /quiet /passive"
```

Which fails with the following:

```
The command 'cmd /S /C "C:\prereqs\WSE30.msi /qn /quiet /passive"' returned a non-zero code: 1603
```

I've tried modifying the RUN command to include logging...

```
RUN "C:\prereqs\WSE30.msi /qn /quiet /passive /lv c:/logs/wse30.txt"
```

...but this creates a condition where the docker build just seems to hang; I've let several of these attempts run for more than an hour and they do not appear to progress or complete.

I've also tried adding an "exit 0" to simply let the build continue if there is an error...

```
RUN "C:\prereqs\WSE30.msi /qn /quiet /passive /lv c:/logs/wse30.txt" ; exit 0
```

..but the result is the same.  The build appears to hang and never complete.

I know that this particular MSI supports unattended/silent installation as I've done so in batch files.

Comment: Have you tried running the install step without the `/quiet` flag to get additional loggin output on why the command failed?

Comment: I have removed the quiet option, but the resulting error message is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DWRoelands , I faced the same issue but I was able to install it on the windowservercore:1909 after installing the all web-serverr and all its subcomponents components.

You will have to set the source of .Net3.5 to the downloaded file of https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/dockerassets/microsoft-windows-netfx3-1909.zip